# Saving HTMLWidget with links to HTML dependencies instead of embedding them

Tags: ggplotly, htmlwidgets

I save my `ggplotly` object using `saveWidget()` function. If I do it with `selfcontained=TRUE` option, all HTML dependencies (javascript libraries and CSS styles) are saved inside the HTML file making it very big. If I use `selfcontained=FALSE`, those dependencies are saved in separate `_file` folder, and linked from the HTML file:

```
<script src="testA_files/htmlwidgets-1.5.3/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<script src="testA_files/plotly-binding-4.9.2.1/plotly.js"></script>
<script src="testA_files/typedarray-0.1/typedarray.min.js"></script>
<script src="testA_files/jquery-3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="testA_files/crosstalk-1.1.1/css/crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="testA_files/crosstalk-1.1.1/js/crosstalk.min.js"></script>
<link href="testA_files/plotly-htmlwidgets-css-1.52.2/plotly-htmlwidgets.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="testA_files/plotly-main-1.52.2/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

For `jQuery`, for example, I know I can use the `code.jquery.com` repository and replace my call with `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"`. Is there similar public repositories for all other dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Of all the dependencies you list, plotly is probably the biggest. The latest plotly refers to this cdn:

```
https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-basic-2.5.1.min.js
```

You can see this by look at the plots dependencies like so:

```
p <- ggplotly(p) %>% partial_bundle(local = FALSE)
p$dependencies
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! I wish other packages had something like that `$dependencies` available...